# Can't get color of button in jQuery using jsColor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscolor

I have a button that acts like trigger for color picker and it should change the color of text in canvas. The library that I'm using is [jscolor](http://jscolor.com/).

```html
<button class="color-picker-btn jscolor {valueElement:'valueElement', onFineChange:'update(this)', value:'ffffff'}"></button>
<input id="valueElement"></input>
```

js:

```js
function update(jscolor) {
        console.log(jscolor);
        canvas.getActiveObject().fill = ( jscolor );
}
```

In the console I get something like this:

```
jscolor {value: "ffffff", valueElement: input#valueElement, styleElement: button.color-picker-btn.jscolor.{valueElement:'valueElement',.onFineChange:'update(this)',.value:'ff…, required: true, refine: true…}
_processParentElementsInDOM:()activeClass:"jscolor-active"
backgroundColor
:
"#FFFFFF"
borderColor
:
"#BBBBBB"
borderRadius
:
8
borderWidth
:
1
buttonColor
:
"#000000"
buttonHeight
:
18
closable
:
false
```

..and a lot more lines. How to get only the color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the this here, the this is the button:

```
<button class="color-picker-btn jscolor {valueElement:'valueElement', onFineChange:'update(this)', value:'ffffff'}"></button>
<input id="valueElement"></input>
```

You can send the input object, like this:

```
<button class="color-picker-btn jscolor {valueElement:'valueElement', onFineChange:'update(valueElement)', value:'ffffff'}"></button>
<input id="valueElement"></input>
```

and in your Javascript function, take the color from the object 'value':

```
function update(jscolor) {
    console.log(jscolor.value);
    canvas.getActiveObject().fill = ( jscolor.value );
}
```

Here is the code in jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/sidanmor/g8odgju6/

Comment: Great solution!